# Mapping one to many with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, one-to-many, dapper

Trying to figure this out, but I can't get it to work. This query:

```
select MultiCollections.*, Collections.* from MultiCollections 
left join MultiCollectionCollections on MultiCollections.Id = MultiCollectionCollections.MultiCollectionId
left join  Collections on MultiCollectionCollections.CollectionId = Collections.Id
where MultiCollections.UserId=5
```

This will return this data:

[image]
As you can see, row 1 and 2 are from the same Title. The data behind them are books.
Row 3 and 4 are also collections but don't have books.

I have two objects in my code:
MultiCollection
Collection

Both correspond with the data given in the result of the query:
Id, UserId and Title are for object MultiCollection. Other data are for the object Collection.

I expect to see three MultiCollections in my C# code:
Action
Drama
Fiction

Action will have 2 collections. Drama and Fiction should be empty.

Instead, I get 4 MultiCollections and none of them contains Collections. My C# code:

```
public IEnumerable<MultiCollection> GetAll(int userId)
    {
        string query = @"select MC.*, C.* from MultiCollections  MC
                        left join MultiCollectionCollections MCC on MC.Id = MCC.MultiCollectionId
                        left join  Collections C on MCC.CollectionId = C.Id
                        where UserId=" + userId;

        using (DbConnection connection = ConnectionFactory())
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection.Query<MultiCollection, List<Collection>, MultiCollection>(query,
                (a, s) =>
                {
                    a.Collections = s;
                    return a;
                });
        }
    }
```

When running the code I would expect this:

```
Action    
    Collections    
       -> Book 1    
       -> Book 2     
Drama    
   Collections    
       Null     
Fiction    
    Collections    
        Null
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What type is `a.Collections`? Is it a `List<Collection>`?

Comment: Yup, List<Collection>

Answer (score 0):

Your c# code should of look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MultiCollection> GetAll(int userId)
{
    string query = @"select MC.*, C.* from MultiCollections  MC
                    left join MultiCollectionCollections MCC on MC.Id = MCC.MultiCollectionId
                    left join  Collections C on MCC.CollectionId = C.Id
                    where UserId = @userId;";

    using (DbConnection connection = ConnectionFactory())
    {
        connection.Open();
        return connection.Query<MultiCollection, Collection, MultiCollection>(query,
            (a, s) =>
            {
                a.Collections = new List<Collection>();
                a.Collections.Add(s);
                return a;
            },
            param: new { userId },
            splitOn: "MultiCollectionId,CollectionId");
    }
}
```

Notice, that `.Query<MultiCollection, Collection, MultiCollection>` is a `Collection` not `List<Collection>` and it is doing `.add()` and not setter.

Comment: Now I still get 4 MultiCollections, instead of 3. The first 2 are the same with each the corresponding book. But both books should be added under one multicollection.

Comment: Ps. a.Collections.add(s) should be a.Collections.Add(s) (capital) and a.Collections is null at first run, so should be initialized... Just saying, no hard feelings

Comment: @KenjiElzerman, yah, np. I'm typing it without any IDE. Just on top of my head.

Comment: I thought so too, but I get this error all the time: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
Parameter name: splitOn

Comment: You probably need both `MultiCollectionId` and `CollectionId`, it's really hard for me to give you the correct answer on that since I don't know your data structure and result sets. The one you posted pretty hard to read. Regardless, the code should be very close...

Comment: @12seconds3 I have added a screenshot of the result set. Is this better?

Comment: @KenjiElzerman Your query is not going to work, there is no matching IDs between your 2 entities on that result set

Comment: that is the whole point. Some MultiCollections have Collections and some don't.

Comment: Well, that the result set is what you want but that's not how dapper works.

Comment: Owke, so what is the alternative? Running multiple queries to get the result?

Comment: Only you know your database structure best, to actually get this working you need that `MultiCollectionId` on your `Collection` Query somehow, then Dapper can understand and map your entities.